# Vim error message E121: Undefined variable: s:visual_black with vim plugin

Tags: vim

Error terminal ubuntu:

Performed the configuration of vim using the plugin `vim plugin` performed the configurations based on the documentation provided by the plugin, but I'm not able to adjust the error, I'm having trouble using colorscheme onedark.

https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug

https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-colorschemes-sweeter-than-fiction

when i try to access any file using vim i always return the error below:

```
userpc in ~ took 15s 
✦ ❯ vim ~/.vimrc

Error detected while processing /home/userpc/.vim/plugged/vim-colorschemes/colors/onedark.vim:
line  122:
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: visual_black " Black out selected text in 16-color visual mode
line  221:
E121: Undefined variable: s:visual_black
E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>17_h
Error detected while processing /home/userpc/.vimrc:
line   85:
E492: Not an editor command: syntaxe on
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

`.vimrc`

```
 set tabstop=3
  2 set expandtab
  3 set number
  4 filetype indent on
  5 set autoindent
  6 set nocompatible
  7 set background=dark
  8 
  9 "Use 24-bit (true-color) mode in Vim/Neovim when outside tmux.
 10 "If you're using tmux version 2.2 or later, you can remove the outermost $TMUX check and use tmux's 24-bit color support
 11 "(see < http://sunaku.github.io/tmux-24bit-color.html#usage > for more information.)
 12 if (empty($TMUX))
 13   if (has("nvim"))
 14     "For Neovim 0.1.3 and 0.1.4 < https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/2198 >
 15     let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1
 16   endif
 17   "For Neovim > 0.1.5 and Vim > patch 7.4.1799 < https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/61be73bb0f965a895bfb064ea3e55476ac175    162 >
 18   "Based on Vim patch 7.4.1770 (`guicolors` option) < https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8a633e3427b47286869aa4b96f2bfc1f    e65b25cd >
 19   " < https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Following-HEAD#20160511 >
 20   if (has("termguicolors"))
 21     set termguicolors
 22   endif
 23 endif
 24 
 25 
 26 let g:airline_theme='onedark'
 27 let g:onedark_termcolors=256
 28 
 29 
 30 let g:onedark_termcolors=16
 31 let g:lightline = {
 32    \ 'colorschema': 'onedark',
 33    \}
 34 "----------------------------------------------
 35 
 36 
 37 
 38 
 39 call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
 40 
 41 " Make sure you use single quotes
 42 
 43 " Shorthand notation; fetches https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align
 44 Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'
 45 
 46 " Any valid git URL is allowed
 47 Plug 'https://github.com/junegunn/vim-github-dashboard.git'
 48 
 49 " Multiple Plug commands can be written in a single line using | separators
 50 Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips' | Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
 51 
 52 " On-demand loading
 53 Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
 54 Plug 'tpope/vim-fireplace', { 'for': 'clojure' }
 55 
 56 " Using a non-default branch
 57 Plug 'rdnetto/YCM-Generator', { 'branch': 'stable' }
 58 
 59 " Using a tagged release; wildcard allowed (requires git 1.9.2 or above)
 60 Plug 'fatih/vim-go', { 'tag': '*' }
 61 
 62 " Plugin options
 63 Plug 'nsf/gocode', { 'tag': 'v.20150303', 'rtp': 'vim' }
 64 
 65 " Plugin outside ~/.vim/plugged with post-update hook
 66 Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }
 67 
 68 " Unmanaged plugin (manually installed and updated)
 69 Plug '~/my-prototype-plugin'
 70 
 71 " Plugin Colorschemes thema
 72 Plug 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
 73 
 74 " OneDarck schemes thema color
 75 Plug 'joshdick/onedark.vim'
 76 
 77 " Polyglot vim 
 78 Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
 79 Plug 'dracula/vim', { 'as': 'dracula' }
 80 
 81 " Initialize plugin system
 82 call plug#end()
 83 
 84 colorscheme onedark
 85 syntaxe on
```

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Well, you have several issues, here.

The most obvious one, and the easiest to fix, is the extra `e` in:

```
syntaxe on
```

Then you have the double install problem: you have two `onedark.vim`. One installed via `Plug 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'` and the other installed via `Plug 'joshdick/onedark.vim'`, which makes no sense.

Then you have the "over-engineered colorscheme problem". `onedark.vim` is a relatively recent part of the sadly ever-growing trend of over-engineered/bloated colorschemes that try to be too clever for their—or their users'—own good.

Where to start?

- `onedark.vim`, being the over-engineered mess it is, relies on an autoloaded script to define its colors.
- The `onedark.vim` in `flazz/vim-colorschemes` is not correctly packaged. It lacks that autoloaded script so it simply can't work out of the box.
- But you are lucky, in a way, because you have *also* installed the original `onedark.vim`, which comes with the necessary autoloaded script, so the `onedark.vim` from `flazz/vim-colorschemes` uses the autoloaded script from `joshdick/onedark.vim`.
- But your luck stops there, because the `onedark.vim` packaged in `flazz/vim-colorschemes` is outdated: it assumes the presence of a `visual_black` key that was removed in [a subsequent version](https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim/pull/271) of the original so the original's autoloaded script is not *that* useful after all.

Now, how do we get out of that mess?

It's simple: get rid of `flazz/vim-colorschemes`.

You will be left with the original `onedark.vim`, which, while still terribly over-engineered, seems to be properly maintained so it can be expected to work in a more controlled manner than a badly packaged "fork".

Comment: [flazz/vim-colorschemes](https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes) seems unmaintained since 2020. There's a fork of it, https://github.com/EvitanRelta/vim-colorschemes which has fixed this issue with onedark.vim and some others. Just another option if someone wants to choose from a selection of themes.